# Permutations of a list where each element is an array of int

Tags: c#, combinatorics

I have list of 90, each element in the list is an int array of 600.
Now i want to perform permutations on this list (not on the int array), i.e. i want to get all possible unique combinations of this list of 90 elements, in short 90! lists.

I am using the `kwCombinatorics` library.

Here is the code.

This exception is thrown on the first foreach statement,
`ArgumentOutOfRangeException` -

> Value is greater than maximum allowed.

```
foreach(var row in new Permutation(image_matrix_90_600.Count).GetRows())
{         
    foreach(var mix in Permutation.Permute(row, image_matrix_90_600))
        {
            // code for saving the individual list to text. 
        }
}
```

Her is the example from http://kwcombinatorics.codeplex.com/

```
using Kw.Combinatorics;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Kw.CombinatoricsExamples
{
    public class Furniture
    {
        private string name;
        public Furniture (string newName) { name = newName; }
        public override string ToString () { return name; }
    }

    public class Fruit
    {
        private string name;
        public Fruit (string newName) { name = newName; }
        public override string ToString () { return name; }
    }

    class PnExample03
    {
        static void Main ()
        {
            var things = new List<object>
            {
                new Fruit ("apple"),
                new Furniture ("bench"),
                new Furniture ("chair")
            };

            // Use permutations to get rearrangements of other objects:

            foreach (var row in new Permutation (things.Count).GetRows())
            {
                foreach (var mix in Permutation.Permute (row, things))
                    Console.Write ("{0} ", mix);
                    Console.WriteLine ();
            }
        }

        /* Output:

        apple bench chair
        apple chair bench
        bench apple chair
        bench chair apple
        chair apple bench
        chair bench apple

        */
    }
}
```

Comment: What is Permutation, mix and row?

Comment: 90! Hahahah :). How many billions of years do you have available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `width` parameter which is used in the constructor `Permutation(int width)` may take values between 0 and 20. Probably the value of `image_matrix_90_600.Count` you are passing in is 90 and that's why you get the exception.

```
/// <summary>
/// Make a new <see cref="Permutation"/> from the supplied
/// <em>width</em> of <see cref="Rank"/> 0.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="width">Number of elements of new sequence.</param>
/// <example>
/// <code source="Examples\Permutation\PnExample01\PnExample01.cs" lang="cs" />
/// </example>
/// <exception cref="ArgumentOutOfRangeException">
/// When <em>width</em> is less than 0 or greater than 20.
/// </exception>
public Permutation (int width)
{
    if (width < 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException ("width", "Value is less than zero.");

    if (width > MaxWidth)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException ("width", "Value is greater than maximum allowed.");

    this.data = new int[width];
    for (int ei = 0; ei < width; ++ei)
        this.data[ei] = ei;

    this.rank = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do this.

90! is approx 1.49 * 10^138

Assuming you could somehow process one billion permutations per second, this would take well over 4 * 10^112 BILLION years. Many, many times the current age of the universe.

Have fun! :)

Comment: BTW, assuming that each permutation is 90 * 600 * 4 bytes in size, the result would consume `2.9 * 10^128` PetaBytes. Because there are  only 10^78 to 10^82 atoms in the universe, **each single atom** in the whole universe would have to store `2.9 * 10^46` PetaBytes of information.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation in XML of `KwCombinatorics` library, `Permute` method throws an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` *When length of source is less than Kw.Combinatorics.Permutation.Width*.

Comment: Check the value of `Kw.Combinatorics.Permutation.Width` in order to find that the problem lies in `source` parameter.